# Ansible - Exception: host not found: {{ item }}

Tags: ansible

I have some task which I wish to `delegate_to` some hosts (finally I want to list them in some var rather than use group from inventory). For this question lets simplify this to (I did exactly the same having a hope it'll help me spot where the problem is):

```
- name Foo
  tamplate:
    dest=/path/to/file
    src=template.j2
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - some.host.in.my.domain
```

This throws an exception:

```
Exception: host not found: {{ item }}
```

Any idea why this doesn't work ? Let me know if you need more details. Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: There's multiple syntax errors in your yaml - are you sure it looks like that?  You have a missing colon after name, and template is misspelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's some kind of [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9828) in ansible 1.8.2. I faced same problem in some other place which worked before I made an upgrade.

Comment: For the completeness, [here the patch](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/3269a349f32a2b5c1fc079a2d174e01c541f444b) to fix it. Thanks a lot pawel7318

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a delegate_to host can be specified with a with_items value - and I don't see why that wouldn't work - the problem is that you can't delegate to a non-existent host.

Not all is lost though; the trick here is to add the hosts dynamically before delegating to them.  Try using the [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/add_host_module.html) action to add the hosts into the ansible play.  Then, you may be able to delegate to them.